# Clickhouse 1.1.54343 Data ingestion in distributed ReplicatedMergeTree table error

Tags: clickhouse

I am facing issue in Data load and merging of the table in Clickhouse 1.1.54343 and not able to insert any data in Clickhouse.

We have 3 node cluster and we add 300 columns to the tables in data ingestion and ingesting data from JSON files.

We were able to save data in the tables

**Create Table**

```
*-- Each Node*
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AudiencePlanner.reached_pod
(
    date Date,
    p_id String,
    language String, 
    city String, 
    state String, 
    platform String, 
    manufacturer String,
    model String, 
    content_id String
) ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/shard1/reached_pod', 'clickhouse1')
PARTITION BY date 
ORDER BY (date, platform, language, city, state, manufacturer, model, content_id, p_id);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AudiencePlanner2.reached_pod
(
    date Date,
    p_id String,
    language String, 
    city String, 
    state String, 
    platform String, 
    manufacturer String,
    model String, 
    content_id String
) ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/shard3/reached_pod', 'clickhouse1')
PARTITION BY date 
ORDER BY (date, platform, language, city, state, manufacturer, model, content_id, p_id);
```

***--- All Nodes***

```
CREATE TABLE AudiencePlanner.reached_pod_all AS AudiencePlanner.reached_pod ENGINE = Distributed(test, '', reached_pod, rand());
```

**Config.xml**

```
<remote_servers>
        <test>
            <shard>
                <weight>1</weight>
                <internal_replication>false</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <host>ip1</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <default_database>AudiencePlanner</default_database>
                    <user>test</user>
                    <password>testpass</password>
                </replica>
                <replica>
                    <host>ip2</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <default_database>AudiencePlanner2</default_database>
                    <user>test</user>
                    <password>testpass</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>
            <shard>
                <weight>1</weight>
                <internal_replication>false</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <host>ip2</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <default_database>AudiencePlanner</default_database>
                    <user>test</user>
                    <password>testpass</password>
                </replica>
                <replica>
                    <host>ip3</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <default_database>AudiencePlanner2</default_database>
                    <user>test</user>
                    <password>testpass</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>
            <shard>
                <weight>1</weight>
                <internal_replication>false</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <host>ip3</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <default_database>AudiencePlanner</default_database>
                    <user>test</user>
                    <password>testpass</password>
                </replica>
                <replica>
                    <host>ip1</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <default_database>AudiencePlanner2</default_database>
                    <user>test</user>
                    <password>testpass</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>
        </dms>
    </remote_servers>
```

**Error log**

```
2018.03.10 07:50:59.990953 [ 31 ] <Trace> AudiencePlanner.reached_pod (StorageReplicatedMergeTree): Executing log entry to merge parts 20180203_111_111_0, 20180203_112_112_0, 20180203_113_113_0 to 20180203_111_113_1
2018.03.10 07:50:59.991204 [ 31 ] <Debug> AudiencePlanner.reached_pod (Merger): Merging 3 parts: from 20180203_111_111_0 to 20180203_113_113_0 into tmp_merge_20180203_111_113_1
2018.03.10 07:50:59.996659 [ 31 ] <Debug> AudiencePlanner.reached_pod (Merger): Selected MergeAlgorithm: Horizontal
2018.03.10 07:50:59.997347 [ 31 ] <Trace> MergeTreeBlockInputStream: Reading 1 ranges from part 20180203_111_111_0, approx. 24576 rows starting from 0
2018.03.10 07:50:59.997417 [ 31 ] <Trace> MergeTreeBlockInputStream: Reading 1 ranges from part 20180203_112_112_0, approx. 8192 rows starting from 0
2018.03.10 07:50:59.997476 [ 31 ] <Trace> MergeTreeBlockInputStream: Reading 1 ranges from part 20180203_113_113_0, approx. 8192 rows starting from 0
2018.03.10 07:51:00.016479 [ 31 ] <Debug> MemoryTracker: Peak memory usage: 1.16 GiB.
2018.03.10 07:51:00.044547 [ 31 ] <Error> DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::queueTask()::<lambda(DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::LogEntryPtr&)>: Code: 76, e.displayText() = 

DB::Exception: Cannot open file /data/clickhouse//data/AudiencePlanner/reached_pod/tmp_merge_20180203_111_113_1/%1F%EF%BF%BD%08%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%EF%BF%BDVrs%EF%BF%BDws%EF%BF%BDu%EF%BF%BDq%EF%BF%BD%0F%09%EF%BF%BD76%EF%BF%BD51P%EF%BF%BDQ%0A%0A%EF%BF%BDw%EF%BF%BDu%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BDw%042%0D%EF%BF%BD%0D%0C%0D%2D%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%08%EF%BF%BD%C6%A6%EF%BF%BD%26%26J%EF%BF%BD%00%EF%BF%BD%1C%EF%BF%BD%1E%3F%00%00%00.bin, errno: 36, strerror: File name too long, e.what() = DB::Exception, Stack trace:

0. /usr/bin/clickhouse-server(StackTrace::StackTrace()+0x15) [0x7317e35]
1. /usr/bin/clickhouse-server(DB::Exception::Exception(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)+0x1e) [0x19caa8e]
2. /usr/bin/clickhouse-server(DB::throwFromErrno(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int, int)+0x1a4) [0x72ffea4]
3. /usr/bin/clickhouse-server(DB::WriteBufferFromFile::WriteBufferFromFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, int, unsigned int, char*, unsigned long)+0x1c5) [0x733d4a5]
4. /usr/bin/clickhouse-server(DB::createWriteBufferFromFileBase(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, int, unsigned int, char*, unsigned long)+0xac) [0x7345c9c]
5. /usr/bin/clickhouse-server(DB::IMergedBlockOutputStream::ColumnStream::ColumnStream(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, DB::CompressionSettings, unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x

I tried detaching the partition but still not able insert any other data, after detaching the error comes like 
2018.03.10 09:00:27.299291 [ 9 ] <Error> reached_pod_all.Distributed.DirectoryMonitor: Code: 76, e.displayText() = 

DB::Exception: Received from ip1:9000. DB::Exception: Cannot open file /data/clickhouse//data/AudiencePlanner/reached_pod/tmp_insert_20180207_21_21_0/%1F%EF%BF%BD%08%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%EF%BF%BDVrs%EF%BF%BDws%EF%BF%BDu%EF%BF%BDq%EF%BF%BD%0F%09%EF%BF%BD76%EF%BF%BD51P%EF%BF%BDQ%0A%0A%EF%BF%BDw%EF%BF%BDu%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BDw%042%0D%EF%BF%BD%0D%0C%0D%2D%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%08%EF%BF%BD%C6%A6%EF%BF%BD%26%26J%EF%BF%BD%00%EF%BF%BD%1C%EF%BF%BD%1E%3F%00%00%00.bin, errno: 36, strerror: File name too long. Stack trace:

0. /usr/bin/clickhouse-server(StackTrace::StackTrace()+0x15) [0x7317e35]
1. /usr/bin/clickhouse-server(DB::Exception::Exception(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)+0x1e) [0x19caa8e]
2. /usr/bin/clickhouse-server(DB::throwFromErrno(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int, int)+0x1a4) [0x72ffea4]
3. /usr/bin/clickhouse-server(DB::WriteBufferFromFile::WriteBufferFromFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, int, unsigned int, char*, unsigned long)+0x1c5) [0x733d4a5]
4. /usr/bin/clickhouse-server(DB::createWriteBufferFromFileBase(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, int, unsigned int, char*, unsigned long)+0xac) [0x7345c9c]
5. /usr/bin/clickhouse-server(DB::IMergedBlockOutputStream::ColumnStream::ColumnStream(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, DB::CompressionSettings, unsigned long, unsigned long)+0xcc) [0x68cd7ac]
6. /usr/bin/clickhouse-server() [0x68ce674]
```

Please help me in identifying and resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem, it was due to number of columns that we were adding dynamically around 1000 of column.

Due to number of columns the filename created long string which gave error in writing in filename.

```
I reduced the number of columns to be inserted and i was able to write the data.
```